# Python List of Functions

Tags: python, list

Is it possible to create a list of functions where you can access them individually? For example:

```
e=0

def a():
   global e
   e=1

def b():
   global e
   e=2

def c():
   global e
   e=3

l=[a(),b(),c()]

l[2]
print e
l[0]
print e
```

Output:

```
>>>3
>>>1
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling your functions at the beginning and storing only their values in the list.

```
e=0

def a():
   global e
   e=1

def b():
   global e
   e=2

def c():
   global e
   e=3

l=[a,b,c]

l[2]()
print e
l[0]()
print e
```

Output

```
>>> 
3
1
```

Comment: Worthy of note: the reason this works is because functions are first class objects in Python. When you refer to `a`, `b`, and `c` this way, you're using variables of those names that happen to contain functions. You can even reassign them.

Answer (score 4):

`l=[a(),b(),c()]` is not a list of function, rather a collections of values returned from calling those functions. In a list the items are evaluated from left to right, so `e` is going to be 3 after this step.

As functions are objects in python so you can do:

```
>>> l = [a, b, c] # creates new references to the functions objects
                  # l[0] points to a, l[1] points to b...
>>> l[0]()
>>> e
1
>>> l[2]()
>>> e
3
>>> l[1]()
>>> e
2
```

Answer (score 0):

As an example: you may change to code to

```
l=[a,b,c]

l[2]()
print e
l[0]()
print e
```

and it'll do what you expect. If you declare a list of functions, do not add the parentheses. Instead put them where you call the function.